# How to create a desktop shortcut to a network drive that will prompt a user for the folder name?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut to a network drive that will prompt a user for the folder name.

We have a document drive that each user has a folder in. Assistants and others need to access their managers drive which we currently manually create a shortcut to.

What I would like is a shortcut that would prompt them for the managers name and then create a shortcut to that users drive on the assistants desktop.

Comment: There a several better solution i would guess. You could write a gpo or batch script checking for a certain AD-propery e.g department or name and depending on that property assingn the user a networkdrive or desktop .lnk

Comment: I would if I had access to do that the network guys don't seem to care because they don't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Well if youre not the admin i dont see any good solution here. Why not just creating shortcurts on the desktop you need like you do now? Do you have that much different managers/assisents?

Comment: Well one solution comes into my mind. You could use the scripting tool AutoIt and create an exe file that show a dropdown field with the managers and an ok button that will open the explorer with the desired folder